# Using rewrite api cause wordpress Stop Working

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have some wordpress website and when i try to change this link :

http://freep3.com/?p=270

to this link

http://freep3.com/songs/270

using this rule in functions.php :

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^song/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

my wordpress stop working !

can anybody know the reason or have some other solutions ?

Comment: is mod_rewrite module enable in your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link in the example and rewrite rule does not match, if link is `http://freep3.com/songs/270` then rule should be

```
add_rewrite_rule('^songs/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

, or even simpler `'^songs/(\d+)/?'`.

Also do not forget to [flush and regenerate](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Example) the rewrite rules.

Comment: I don't think it explain why the rewrite rule made the OP site down.